# Selecting the most specific row match based on multiple column values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently working on a content targeting feature , where we are showing different pages to doctors based on their category/country/region.

So here is how our Doctor table looks like,

```
 id |  name  | age | region | country | doctor_category 
----+--------+-----+--------+---------+-----------------
  1 | Deepak |  25 | APAC   | JP      | GP
  2 | Anil   |  25 | APAC   | JP      | null
  3 | Ajay   |  27 | APAC   | IN      | null
  4 | Amit   |  28 | NA     | CN      | null
```

All our pages are dynamically generated, Here is how our page table looks like,

```
 page_id | target_region | target_countries | target_categories 
---------+---------------+------------------+-------------------
       1 | APAC          | null             | null
       2 | APAC          | JP               | null
       3 | APAC          | JP               | GP
       4 | null          | null             | null
```

Page 4 is the default page if no condition matches

Expected output: (Best specific match)

`User(1) => Page(3)`

`User(2) => Page(2)`

`User(3) => Page(1)`

`User(4) => Page(4)`

I tried a lot with `CASE / GROUP BY/ DISTINCT ON` in posgresql , but no success, for one or more scenario its failing. I am not a hardcore database guy so I may be missing some built functions to achieve the same.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why is user 4 shown a page with region null while its region is North America?

Comment: mysql and postgresql are two different products. Please remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: and likewise, why page 1 has no country associated while user 3 has country "IN" specified?

Comment: @FabianPijcke User 4 will see the Page 4 because no page is targeted for North america, so he will see the default page

Comment: if one doctor equally corresponds to multiple pages, then you need choose all pages or just one?

Comment: @FabianPijcke: pages can be targeted to a whole region or to a specific country. So if a page is targeted to whole region like `EMEA/APAC`, in that scenario country will be null

Comment: is it mysql or postgresql?

Comment: @Vecchiasignora postgresql

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @FabianPijcke In my experience that's usually not the case. More over, there is a specific tag for this: [rdbms-agnostic.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rdbms-agnostic/info)

Comment: And indeed you were right :-) Besides I did not know that tag ^^ I'll drop my upper comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution, working only in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  id,
  first_value(page_id) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id
    ORDER BY target_categories IS NULL, target_countries IS NULL, target_region IS NULL
  )
FROM doctors
  LEFT JOIN pages ON (target_categories = doctor_category OR target_categories IS NULL)
    AND (target_countries = country OR target_countries IS NULL)
    AND (target_region = region OR target_region is null);
```

Note that your problem is not strictly well defined. As if a page matches the country but has no category, and another page matches the category but has no country, it is not clear which one has to be chosen.

The ties are broken by choosing which parameter has the highest priority. This is the job of the `ORDER BY` line. The first column has the highest priority. Feel free to change the order in which they occur.

Otherwise the query works like this:

- Select all the pages that are acceptable for the doctor
- Order them by accuracy for each doctor
- Select only the first value for each doctor
- As the query would yield one (identical) row per acceptable page, we drop repeated rows using DISTINCT.

Comment: will check your query , Priority order is category > country > region. If nothing is found get the page will all null values

Comment: Ok, I will update my query to respect this priority order. The null-values page will always be an "acceptable" page so it will default to this page :-)

Comment: For User 3 and 4 , no page gets selected.

Comment: Well, with the data you provided, I do have a page associated to users 3 and 4 ^^. What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: For `user-3` the below condition fails, `AND (target_country = country OR target_country IS NULL)` so it does not return any page. sqlfiddle does not seems to working otherwise i could have prepared the scenario for u.

Comment: But ... for pages 1 and 4, target_country is null, isn't it? The condition should succeed for these two pages, and page 1 should be picked because it is the more relevant. That's what happens on my test database at least :-/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148205/discussion-between-deepak-kumar-padhy-and-fabian-pijcke).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select d.*, p.Page_Id 
from Doctors as d left join PageTable as p 
on (d.Region = COALESCE(p.target_region,'NULL') 
    and COALESCE(d.Country,'NULL') = COALESCE(p.targer_countries,'NULL') 
    and COALESCE(d.Doctor_Category,'NULL') = COALESCE(p.targer_categories,'NULL'))
```

or second wiche gets clear first match row

```
select d.*, (select Page_Id from PageTabl as p where d.Region = COALESCE(p.target_region,'NULL') 
    and COALESCE(d.Country,'NULL') = COALESCE(p.targer_countries,'NULL') 
    and COALESCE(d.Doctor_Category,'NULL') = COALESCE(p.targer_categories,'NULL')
    LIMIT 1) as Page_Id
from Doctors as d
```

and you can change coalesces depends on  your logic

Comment: Parentheses are not balanced ^^. And why do you default null values to North America?

Comment: i didnt understand that it's norht America)) i understtod that it defualt value)

Comment: and about parentheses i have fixed it